# What is the maximum eves height allowed on a log cabin when you have dug down?

Tags: fence, building-regulations

We have built a log cabin in our garden, believing it to be "permitted development", and therefore not need planning permission. We have two things that we are not sure about though and are a little worried in case we should have obtained a planning permission.

Our land is sloped, so we dug down the high side. We made our eves 2.7m high, despite the max usually being 2.5m,but dug down way more than the 200mm difference. We have read that the inspectors measure from the ground immediately adjacent to the building at the highest point of the building. If you were building in brick, you might leave the mud right up against the wall, but as we are building in wood we have dug a good channel right around the building and built a retaining wall to keep the high land back away from the wooden walls.  Now the high land is maybe 500mm away from the wall. Will they still measure from this or from the ground level that we have dug down to?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Also, one corner of our building is a little less than the required 2 meters away from our boundary fence, but the other side of the fence is just an alleyway - does anyone know if you still have to keep the 2 meters distance from this kind of fence, when building over 2.5 meters to ridge height???